# How to avoid multiple Streams with Java 8

Tags: java, java-stream, iteration, collectors

I am having the below code

```
trainResponse.getIds().stream()
        .filter(id -> id.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("Company"))
        .findFirst()
        .ifPresent(id -> {
            domainResp.setId(id.getId());
        });

trainResponse.getIds().stream()
        .filter(id -> id.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("Private"))
        .findFirst()
        .ifPresent(id ->
            domainResp.setPrivateId(id.getId())
        );
```

Here I'm iterating/streaming the list of `Id` objects `2` times.

The only difference between the two streams is in the `filter()` operation.

How to achieve it in ***single iteration***, and what is the best approach (*in terms of **time** and **space complexity***) to do this?

Comment: Probably not without making the streams excessively complicated ... defeating the purpose of using streams!  If you want to avoid doing two iterations, use a `for` each loop.

Comment: You can extract the code to a method to reuse it, but streams are not meant for branching logic.

Comment: @shmosel - among other things, it is difficult to get the short-circuiting effect of `first()` on a combined stream.  And that could negate any possible benefit of combining the two streams.  As you say ...

Comment: "Only difference between two iterations is filter" is not correct, the used setter is also different! (otherwise you could *merge* the conditions in one filter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that with Stream IPA in one pass though the given set of data and without increasing memory consumption (*i.e. the result will contain only* `id`s *having required attributes*).

For that, you can create a custom `Collector` that will expect as its parameters a `Collection` attributes to look for and a `Function` responsible for extracting the attribute from the stream element.

That's how this generic collector could be implemented.

```
/** *
 * @param <T> - the type of stream elements
 * @param <F> - the type of the key (a field of the stream element)
 */
class CollectByKey<T, F> implements Collector<T, Map<F, T>, Map<F, T>> {
    private final Set<F> keys;
    private final Function<T, F> keyExtractor;
    
    public CollectByKey(Collection<F> keys, Function<T, F> keyExtractor) {
        this.keys = new HashSet<>(keys);
        this.keyExtractor = keyExtractor;
    }
    
    @Override
    public Supplier<Map<F, T>> supplier() {
        return HashMap::new;
    }
    
    @Override
    public BiConsumer<Map<F, T>, T> accumulator() {
        return this::tryAdd;
    }
    
    private void tryAdd(Map<F, T> map, T item) {
        F key = keyExtractor.apply(item);
        if (keys.remove(key)) {
            map.put(key, item);
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public BinaryOperator<Map<F, T>> combiner() {
        return this::tryCombine;
    }
    
    private Map<F, T> tryCombine(Map<F, T> left, Map<F, T> right) {
        right.forEach(left::putIfAbsent);
        return left;
    }
    
    @Override
    public Function<Map<F, T>, Map<F, T>> finisher() {
        return Function.identity();
    }
    
    @Override
    public Set<Characteristics> characteristics() {
        return Collections.emptySet();
    }
}
```

`main()` - demo (dummy `Id` class is not shown)

```
public class CustomCollectorByGivenAttributes {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Id> ids = List.of(new Id(1, "Company"), new Id(2, "Fizz"),
                               new Id(3, "Private"), new Id(4, "Buzz"));
        
        Map<String, Id> idByType = ids.stream()
                .collect(new CollectByKey<>(List.of("Company", "Private"), Id::getType));
        
        idByType.forEach((k, v) -> {
            if (k.equalsIgnoreCase("Company")) domainResp.setId(v);
            if (k.equalsIgnoreCase("Private")) domainResp.setPrivateId(v);
        });
    
        System.out.println(idByType.keySet()); // printing keys - added for demo purposes
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
[Company, Private]
```

*Note*, after the set of keys becomes empty (i.e. all resulting data has been fetched) the further elements of the stream will get ignored, but still all remained data is required to be processed.

Comment: any Java library providing collecting by key option/method?

Comment: @Remo There's no built-in collectors similar to one listed above. You can create your own collector by using static method `Collector.of()` in line (right on the spot - inside the `collect()`), or by implementing the `Collector` interface. But firstly, I suggest you to become familiar with all standard built-in collectors from the [`Collectors`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html) class and get a firm knowledge of what they are capable.

Comment: Nicely done!  +1  I don't develop my own collectors much since I seldom come across a use case.  Need to start playing with it though.

Comment: @WJS Thanks! Writing collectors can be really funny and absorbing, the important thing to remember is that collector should be stateful (in the sense that only the contents of its mutable container should change).

Answer (score 1):

IMO, the two streams solution is the most readable.  And it may even be the most efficient solution using streams.

IMO, the best way to avoid multiple streams is to use a classical loop.  For example:

```
// There may be bugs ...

boolean seenCompany = false;
boolean seenPrivate = false;
for (Id id: getIds()) {
   if (!seenCompany && id.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("Company")) {
      domainResp.setId(id.getId());
      seenCompany = true;
   } else if (!seenPrivate && id.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("Private")) {
      domainResp.setPrivateId(id.getId());
      seenPrivate = true;
   }
   if (seenCompany && seenPrivate) {
      break;
   }
}
```

It is unclear whether that is more efficient to performing one iteration or two iterations.  It will depend on the class returned by `getIds()` and the code of iteration.

The complicated stuff with two flags is how you replicate the short circuiting behavior of `findFirst()` in your 2 stream solution.  I don't know if it is possible to do that *at all* using one stream.  If you can, it will involve something pretty cunning code.

But as you can see your original solution with 2 stream is clearly easier to understand than the above.

---

The main point of using streams is to make your code simpler.  It is not about efficiency.  When you try to do complicated things to make the streams more efficient, you are probably defeating the (true) purpose of using streams in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

For your list of ids, you could just use a map, then assign them after retrieving, if present.

```
Map<String, Integer> seen = new HashMap<>();

for (Id id : ids) {
    if (seen.size() == 2) {
        break;
    }
    seen.computeIfAbsent(id.getType().toLowerCase(), v->id.getId());
}
```

If you want to test it, you can use the following:

```
record Id(String getType, int getId) {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("[%s,%s]", getType, getId);
    }
}

Random r = new Random();
List<Id> ids = r.ints(20, 1, 100)
        .mapToObj(id -> new Id(
                r.nextBoolean() ? "Company" : "Private", id))
        .toList();
```

**Edited to allow only certain types to be checked**

If you have more than two types but only want to check on certain ones, you can do it as follows.

- the process is the same except you have a `Set` of allowed types.
- You simply check to see that your are processing one of those types by using `contains`.

```
Map<String, Integer> seen = new HashMap<>();

Set<String> allowedTypes = Set.of("company", "private");
for (Id id : ids) {
    String type = id.getType();

    if (allowedTypes.contains(type.toLowerCase())) {
        if (seen.size() == allowedTypes.size()) {
            break;
        }
        seen.computeIfAbsent(type,
                v -> id.getId());
    }
}
```

Testing is similar except that additional types need to be included.

- create a list of some types that could be present.
- and build a list of them as before.
- notice that the size of allowed types replaces the value `2` to permit more than two types to be checked before exiting the loop.

```
List<String> possibleTypes = 
      List.of("Company", "Type1", "Private", "Type2");
Random r = new Random();
List<Id> ids =
        r.ints(30, 1, 100)
                .mapToObj(id -> new Id(possibleTypes.get(
                        r.nextInt((possibleTypes.size()))),
                        id))
                .toList();
```

Comment: incase if we get more than 2 types, Map will store only first 2 types with id, right? It's possible to miss the expected types with id

Comment: That is true.  Based on your question,  I didn't know there would be more than two types.  But see my edited answer.  It is pretty easily handled using a set of allowed types.

Answer (score 0):

You can group by type and check the resulting map.
I suppose the type of `ids` is `IdType`.

```java
Map<String, List<IdType>> map = trainResponse.getIds()
                                .stream()
                                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                                                     id -> id.getType().toLowerCase()));

Optional.ofNullable(map.get("company")).ifPresent(ids -> domainResp.setId(ids.get(0).getId()));
Optional.ofNullable(map.get("private")).ifPresent(ids -> domainResp.setPrivateId(ids.get(0).getId()));
```

Comment: I suspect that building the map will be more expensive than two iterations ... with `first()` shortcuts.

Comment: bah, (mis)using `Optional` to hide `null` check

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend a traditionnal for loop. In addition of being easily scalable, this prevents you from traversing the collection multiple times.
Your code looks like something that'll be generalised in the future, thus my generic approch.

Here's some pseudo code (with errors, just for the sake of illustration)

```
Set<String> matches = new TreeSet<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
for(id : trainResponse.getIds()) {

    if (! matches.add(id.getType())) {
        continue;
    }

    switch (id.getType().toLowerCase()) {

        case "company":
            domainResp.setId(id.getId());
            break;

        case "private":
            ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines can might work, it would go through the whole stream though, and won't stop at the first occurrence.
But assuming a small stream and only one Id for each type, why not?

```
Map<String, Consumer<String>> setters = new HashMap<>();
setters.put("Company", domainResp::setId);
setters.put("Private", domainResp::setPrivateId);

trainResponse.getIds().forEach(id -> {
    if (setters.containsKey(id.getType())) {
        setters.get(id.getType()).accept(id.getId());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use the `Collectors.filtering` from **Java 9** onwards to collect the values based on condition.

For this scenario, I have changed code like below

```
final Map<String, String> results = trainResponse.getIds()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.filtering(
                id -> id.getType().equals("Company") || id.getIdContext().equals("Private"),
                Collectors.toMap(Id::getType, Id::getId, (first, second) -> first)));
```

And getting the `id` from `results` Map.